# Powershell DSC: Error while installing using DSC Script

Tags: powershell, dsc

When I run the below script it does install Web Platform Installer and does install URLReWrite. But it end it terminates with error.

```
configuration SetupVm 
{ 
    node ("localhost") 
    { 
        Package WebPi_Installation
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0"
            Path = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
            ProductId = '4D84C195-86F0-4B34-8FDE-4A17EB41306A'
            Arguments = ''
            DependsOn = @("[WindowsFeature]IISMgmtConsole")
        }

        Package UrlRewrite
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "URL Rewrite 2.0"
            Path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe"
            ProductId = ''
            Arguments = "/install /products:UrlRewrite2 /AcceptEula"
            DependsOn = @("[Package]WebPi_Installation")
        }
    } 
} 

SetupVm

Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\SetupVm -Wait -Verbose -Force
```

> Validate-StandardArguments, Path was C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] The path extension was
> .exe
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] Ensure is Present
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] product is
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] product as boolean is False
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] The package URL Rewrite 2.0 is not installed
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite]
> Validate-StandardArguments, Path was C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] The path extension was .exe
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] Package configuration starting
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] The binary is an EXE
>
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] Starting C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe with /install /products:UrlRewrite2 /AcceptEula
>
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] Starting process
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe with arguments /install /products:UrlRewrite2 /AcceptEula
>
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: [[Package]UrlRewrite] The machine requires a reboot
> VERBOSE: [tktestdsc4]: LCM: [ End Set ] [[Package]UrlRewrite] in
> 55.5920 seconds.
>
> **PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_PackageResource failed to execute**
> **Set-TargetResource functionality with error message:** Package from
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd-x64.exe was
> installed, but the specified ProductId and/or Name does not
>
> match package details
>
> - CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
> - PSComputerName : localhost
>
> The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.
>
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
> - PSComputerName : localhost
>
> VERBOSE: Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
>
> VERBOSE: Time taken for configuration job to complete is 70.57 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't specify the productId, so it tries to verify the package is installed using the productId and fails (obviously).

If the product doesn't have the productId you can install it using script extension, if it has, add productId to the `URL Rewrite` resource

Answer (score 0):

For anybody revisiting this, the solution that worked for us was to install manually using:

```
.\WebpiCmd-x64.exe /install /products:UrlRewrite2 /AcceptEula
```

and then running the following in powershell:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize
```

which resulted in:

```
{9BCA2118-F753-4A1E-BCF3-5A820729965C} IIS URL Rewrite Module 2
```

We then added this productId to the dsc with the corresponding name, etc:

```
Package URLRewriteInstallation
{
  Ensure = "Present"
  Name = "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2"
  Path = $Node.WebPiCmdPath
  ProductId = '9BCA2118-F753-4A1E-BCF3-5A820729965C'
  Arguments = "/install /products:UrlRewrite2 /AcceptEula"
  DependsOn = @("[Package]WebPlatformInstaller", "[Script]PIProxy")
}
```

And the urlrewrite was installed successfully